# Alternating row color except when cell already has a color in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code and it alternates row colors to grey and white:

```
$('tr:even').each(function(i){ $(this).find('td').css('background-color','white');});
$('tr:odd').each(function(i){ $(this).find('td').css('background-color','grey');});
```

except some cells are colored red. How do I make it so that the alternating rows of grey and white does not replace the red cells? The code above removes all red cells and replaces them with white or grey. Thank you.

Comment: How is the red background set? Using a css class name or as a `background-color` property on the cell itself? e.g. `<td background-color='red'>`?

Comment: Use a class rather than setting css directly, then you can use css specificity to control which color takes precedence.

Comment: This table is being pulled from a remote server, but I hope this helps. <script src="http://remoteserver/sorttable.js"></script>
<style type = "text/css">';
td.alert{background-color: #FF0000;}</style>

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you just use css for all of it:

```
tr:even td {
    background-color: grey;
}
tr:odd td {
     background-color: white;
}
tr:even td.red, tr:odd td.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Old browser hack:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table tr:even').addClass('even');
  $('table tr:odd').addClass('odd');
});

tr.even td {
    background-color: grey;
}
tr.odd td {
     background-color: white;
}
tr.even td.red, tr.odd td.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

If it's still not working, it sounds like inline styles are being applied from the other server, in which case, as much as I hate to use !important, I like it better than a slow jquery solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table tr:even').addClass('even');
  $('table tr:odd').addClass('odd');
});

tr.even td {
    background-color: grey !important;
}
tr.odd td {
     background-color: white !important;
}
tr.even td.red, tr.odd td.red {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: believe it or not, there are a few widely used browsers that still don't support that, even though i'd still do it this way in spite of those users using said browser.

Comment: The css above makes sense to me too but it doesn't work. I think it's because this table has its own css from a remote server and I can't change its properties. Doing this works $('tr:even').each(function(i){ $(this).find('td').css('background-color', i%2 ? 'rgb(212,212,212)':'white');}); except the red cells are replaced with white or grey.

Comment: try it with !important, I modified answer

Comment: I know CSS is the way to go with this so I'll use your code with !important soon as I access the server later today and report back with the results. Thank you.

Comment: The CSS does not work because there is a CSS already set for table I'm pulling from a remote server: ` <style type = "text/css">';
  td.datacellone{
   background-color: #C0C0C0;
  }
  th.datacellheader{
   background-color: #6A5ACD;
  }
  td.alert{
   background-color: #FF0000;
  }
  td.orange{
   background-color: #FFA500;
  }
  td.green{
   background-color: #008000;
  }
 </style>`.

Comment: Your CSS code above overrides a CSS already set for table I'm pulling from a remote server: `<style type = "text/css">';
td.alert{background-color: #FF0000;}</style>`. td.alert is red. So if I use your CSS code the grey and white override the red cells also. `$('tr:even').each(function(i){ $(this).find('td').css('background-color', 'lightblue');});` also overrides the red cells. Tried Nelson's answer below `$('tr:even').not(filter_red)` but it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: Any CSS does not override the grey rows. Seems like the server side has the td cells hardcoded like `<td style="background color:grey">`. White rows are overridden fine. So if I want to select a grey row like this `$('tr:nth-child(1)').each(function(i){ $(this).find('td').css('background-color', 'lightblue');});` it remains grey but when I do the same on a white row like `$('tr:nth-child(2)')` it gets overridden with light blue. Sigh.

Comment: Tried that and no go. This highlights row 2 light blue: `$('tr:nth-child(2)').each(function(i){ $(this).find('td').css('background-color', 'lightblue');});`. Can you please help me so that the red cells on row 2 do not get overridden by light blue? I tried Nelson's code below: `var filter_red = function(){ return $(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'};` `$('tr:nth-child(2)').not(filter_red)` but the red cells are still overridden. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/#not-functionindex) with a function parameter, like this:

```
var filter_red = function(){ return $(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'};
$('tr:even').not(filter_red).REST OF YOUR CODE..
```

Comment: No browser in existence would actually return `red`, but more likely `rbg(255,0,0)` ?

Comment: I was trying my above code and realize that, I've changed it for what is actually returning for red.. thank you.

Comment: Tried your suggestion above with color #FF0000 (red) and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

A class for odd or even rows (not both!) would make this easy.

```
$("tr").filter(":even").addClass("even");
```

css:

```
tr.even td {
    background-color: #ededed;
}
```

Styles set directly on elements will take precedence over what is in the stylesheet, so if your red css is set directly on the cell, it will override.

Comment: Hey Kevin, your first line of code goes in my html and the rest goes to css right? Hmm it doesn't work. This code works $('tr:even').each(function(i){ $(this).find('td').css('background-color', i%2 ? 'grey':'white');}); except the red cells are replaced with white or grey. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, the first line would go where your current javascript code is, and the css would go in your stylesheet. I simplified both, but what was previously there should have worked too. Most likely the extra css you mentioned is taking precedence, you'll have to make the css above more specific so that it overrides the existing css.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Tried your suggestion and it does not work. I tried it even on my local server with a static table.

Comment: It's not working because of the existing styles. I can't see the existing styles. *"you'll have to make the css above more specific so that it overrides the existing css"* Your problem at this point is too localized. `!important` is a terrible solution, It should not be used more than temporarily. Instead, the css should be refactored.

Comment: Here is the existing style pulled from right-clicking the webpage and viewing source: <style type = "text/css">';
td.datacellone{background-color: #C0C0C0;} th.datacellheader{ background-color: #6A5ACD;} td.alert{ background-color: #FF0000;}
td.orange{background-color: #FFA500;} td.green{background-color: #008000;}</style>. The alert is the red one, but as you can see there are more than just the red. You're right when you said styles set directly on elements will take precedence over what is in the stylesheet... continued below...

Comment: You're right, but that is my issue. I don't want styles I set directly on elements to take precedence. I want what's in the stylesheet to take precedence. $('tr:even').each(function(i){ $(this).find('td').css('background-color', 'white');}); will override all red on even rows to white. So how do I retain the stylesheet so that the red,orange,etc. cells remain red,orange,etc.?

Comment: If you changed the colored css styles to include the table and tr as parents, it would be specific enough to override the even style. `table tr td.orange {background-color: #FFA500;}`

Comment: I put your code `table tr td.orange {background-color: #FFA500;}` in my css but `$('tr:even').each(function(i){ $(this).find('td').css('background-color', 'white');});` is still taking precedence.

Comment: Of course it does, you're still setting inline css instead of using a class such as in my code. inline css overrides everything but !important.

Comment: This works `$('tr:even').each(function(i){ $(this).find('td').css('background-color', 'white');});`. So forget CSS for now. Can I do something like `var filter_green = function(){ return $('td.green').css('background-color') == '#008000'};`, `$('tr:even').not(filter_green);` to keep white from replacing the green cells? My syntax is wrong it doesn't work. Please correct.

Comment: sure, you could... but it seems so unnecessary. that's almost worse than using !important everywhere.